# CKEditor removing <html> and <body> tags

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I using CKEditor, and if I click the Source button and paste HTML code like below :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" />
</head>
<body>
<p>test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and click to Source again and then submit the form, the `html` , `head` and , `body` tags are removed and just stays `<p>test</p>`!

CKEditor configuration:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('content', {
            extraPlugins: 'font,panelbutton,colorbutton,colordialog,justify,indentblock,aparat,buyLink',
            autoGrow_onStartup: true,
            enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
            FullPage : false,
            allowedContent : true,
            ProtectedTags : 'html|head|body'
        });
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to edit an entire HTML page, with `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` elements, you need to set the [`config.fullPage`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-fullPage) option to `true`:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'content', {
    fullPage: true,
    extraPlugins: 'font,panelbutton,colorbutton,colordialog,justify,indentblock,aparat,buyLink',
    // You may want to disable content filtering because if you use full page mode, you probably
    // want to  freely enter any HTML content in source mode without any limitations.
    allowedContent: true,
    autoGrow_onStartup: true,
    enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR
} );
```

Pay attention to using proper case (`fullPage` is not `FullPage`) in your configuration. See also the following resources for more information:

- [Editing Complete HTML Pages](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/fullpage.html) sample
- [Full Page Editing with Document Properties Plugin](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_fullpage)

If you want to use the `config.autoGrow_onStartup` option, you need to include the [Auto Grow](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/autogrow.html) plugin in your setup.

Last but not least, changing the [Enter Mode](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-enterMode) setting to `BR` or `DIV` is not recommended. The default [`CKEDITOR.ENTER_P`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-property-ENTER_P) mode is fully supported by all editor features and plugins and is also the most correct one in terms of best practices for creating web content.

If you do it to control paragraph spacing, you should use stylesheets instead. Edit the `contents.css` file and set up a suitable margin value for `<p>` elements, for example:

```
p { margin: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code to prevent editor to remove 'HEAD/BODY/HTML' tags from your source code:-

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {              
    fullPage: true,
    allowedContent: true,
    autoGrow_onStartup: true,
    enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR
});
```